# Cannot write to mounted (external) HDD

Tags: linux, usb, debian, mount, powerpc

I have tried mounting my external (usb) HDD, but eventhough the permissions match (between the user and the mounted disk) I cannot write, even as root. I tried mounting using pmount and "normal" mount.

System info:

```
Linux b2 2.6.39.4-4 #1 Fri Aug 19 14:41:59 CEST 2011 ppc GNU/Linux
```

User info:

```
zero@b2:~$ id -a
uid=1001(zero) gid=100(users) groups=100(users),46(plugdev)
```

pmount test:

```
zero@b2:~$ pmount /dev/sdb1 HDD
zero@b2:~$ mount
...
/dev/sdb1 on /media/HDD type ntfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,uid=1001,gid=100,umask=077,nls=utf8)

zero@b2:~$ stat /media/HDD/
File: `/media/HDD/'
Size: 4096          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 512    directory
Device: 811h/2065d  Inode: 5           Links: 1
Access: (0700/drwx------)  Uid: ( 1001/    zero)   Gid: (  100/   users)

zero@b2:~$ touch /media/HDD/testtouch
touch: cannot touch `/media/HDD/testtouch': Permission denied
```

I also cannot add any new directories. 
Interestingly enough I CAN edit and save existing files (but not copy etc.)

test writing to existing file:

```
root@b2:/home/zero# mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 -o umask=022,gid=100,uid=1001 TEST/
root@b2:/home/zero# mount -l
...
/dev/sdb1 on /home/zero/TEST type ntfs (rw,umask=022,gid=100,uid=1001)

zero@b2:~$ cat TEST/test 
zero@b2:~$ echo "writing text" > TEST/test 
zero@b2:~$ cat TEST/test 
writing text
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read/write access to NTFS filesystems in the Linux kernel. Use ntfs-3g (FUSE) if you need read/write access.

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/HDD
sudo touch /media/HDD/I_can_write,_my_friends
```

NTFS-3G homepage:

- http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/

More or support of NTFS in Debian:

- https://wiki.debian.org/NTFS

Comment: Ok, but how come that I can edit existing files? Should that be the case?
Looking at /var/log/syslog:
/var/log/syslog:Jan  4 16:01:01 b2 kernel: NTFS driver 2.1.30 [Flags: R/W MODULE]
I got the impression that writing should be possible :\

Comment: @henrikz: you can't get read/write access to a NTFS filesystem using regular ntfs module from the Linux kernel. Please use NTFS-3G

Comment: Installed ntfs-3g, works great thanks!
By the way, I updated my original post; just out of curiosity, any idea on why I can write to existing files (with the default ntfs driver)?

Comment: @henrikz: I don't know. It's really strange, but I think that is possible because NTFS support in the kernel is not reliable